# NGINX Reverse Proxy Is Not Retaining Proper HostName

Tags: tomcat, nginx, jira, reverse-proxy

I've added the following configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
upstream jira  {
      server xx.xx.xx.xx:8080;
}

# redirect non-ssl Jira to ssl
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  jira.example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://jira.example.com$1 permanent;
}

#
# The Jira server
#
server {
    listen       xx.xx.xx.xx:443;
    server_name  jira.example.com;

    ssl on;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/jira.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/jira.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://jira;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        # Password
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;

        # Don't forward auth to Tomcat
        proxy_set_header   Authorization "";
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

But for some reason, after NGINX authorization, it just redirects to: `htttp://jira/secure/MyJiraHome.jspa`. `https` and server name is not retained. Probably I'm doing something wrong in the configuration. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the <Connector> from JIRA's conf/server.xml?

Comment: `proxy_set_header Host $host`

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen. That was the trick. And also I had to add the `scheme` "https", with `proxyName` & `proxyPort` in the `conf/server.xml` of Jira.